# Widget does not work when app is transfered to SD Card. What is solution for it?

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

My android music player when transferred to the SD card then it does not show in the widget (It does not show in the widget list). You cannot set widget in such cases. Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

Do not allow the app to be moved to removable storage, since [your app has an app widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html#ShouldNot). Do this by either removing [your `android:installLocation` attribute](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install) or setting its value to `internalOnly`.